# How can i stop this addition overload from changing the parameter's value?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, addition

```
    VecXd &operator+=(VecXd<T> &addend){
        if(dimension != addend.dimension)
            cout << "The vector dimensions are not equal";
        else{
            for(int i=0; i< dimension; i++)
                vector[i] = vector[i] + addend.vector[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

 friend VecXd &operator+(VecXd<T> &vec, VecXd<T> &addend){
         return vec+=addend;
     }
```

When doing  a + b, the first 'a' changes to the sum as well. I thought by using a reference, I wouldn't effect the original vectors. How do I do this without it also changing 'a'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `vec` to `operator+` by value instead of by reference. Alternatively, pass it by `const` reference and make a copy. Also, don't return a reference from `operator+` -- there's no object for you to return a reference to.

```
 friend VecXd operator+(const VecXd<T> &vec, const VecXd<T> &addend){
     VecXd<T> copy(vec);
     return copy+=addend;
 }
```

The object that results from the addition has to be a temporary, since there's no permanent place to put it. So you can't return it by reference.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did try that but I get this error:  binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const VecXd<T>'

Comment: @user2789563 That's because you didn't make a copy and so were trying to mutilate the input parameter.

Comment: Yeah. After i wrote that, I made the copy and the program ran but when it reaches that point, it breaks and gives me a message saying unhandled exception at ...... in VecXd.exe    std::bad_alloc at memory location .....

Comment: Scratch that, it works now. Forgot to remove the return by reference. Thank you so much!!